# How to provide a facade class to an existing interface in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I would like to provide a facade class to the existing [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html) (say MyAmazonS3Client), so that I get the flexibility to add my additional helper methods apart from the existing client. So the end users of the MyAmazonS3Client interface, should be able to instantiate the MyAmazonS3Client class and can call existing methods as well as helper methods which we write.

Comment: And what's your concrete problem?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I would like to add additional helper methods to the AmazonS3Client interface and also a provide a mechanism to access the original methods. I don't want to write down the original methods and do a delegation, looking for a generic mechanism to call the methods with any kind of varargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about extending `AmazonS3Client` adding as much helper methods as you need?

Comment: How do you handle the instantiation of MyAmazonS3Client for different constructor arguments they already have?

Comment: Like everyone does. Create a constructor for each inherited taking the same parameters having ``super(<parameters>)``.